# Is it possible to multiply the x coordinates of a plot by a certain factor using pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a pgf plot. Now the scale on the x-axis is at the moment frequency, hz, but it should be rad/s to save myself time exporting the file again is it possible to multiply the x-coordinate of every data point with a certain factor easily in pgf plots? In this case 2*pi?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

use `x expr` as in

```
\addplot table[x expr=\thisrowno{0}*2*pi, y index=1] {\table};
```

assuming that your abscissas are stored in the first column of a table
loaded in the macro `\table` and your ordinates in the second.

More details are given on page 29 of the `pgfplots` manual.

Comment: How'd you do that with coordinates ?
`\addplot [...]
coordinates {
(0, 1)
(1, 4)
(2, 14)
};` ?

Answer (score 10):

Yes it is! From the `pgfplots` manual:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xtick={0,1.5708,...,10},
    domain=0:2*pi,
    scaled x ticks={real:3.1415},
    xtick scale label code/.code={$\cdot \pi$}]
    \addplot {sin(deg(x))};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The option of interest is the `scaled x ticks={real:3.1415}`, which tells pgfplots to scale the x values by a factor of 3.1415. You can switch off the "times PI" part below the axis by removing the `xtick scale label code/.code={$\cdot \pi$}` code.

Comment: the OP wants to multiply the domain by a certain factor (2\pi), not to change the tick labels appearance. See Alfred M. answer (or x filter key from the manual).

Comment: But in the outcome, this should be the same, whether I scale the axis to show the "wrong" data points at the "right" x value or whether I multiply the values to get them to the right value, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes you are correct Benedikt, but that is not what I wanted. But thanks for your answer aswell :)

Comment: As far as I can see, the ``real:<num>`` scales the axis by dividing all the axis points by ``<num>´´. So if you want to end up with {2\pi}^2, you would have to scale the axis with 1/(2\pi)...

Comment: I think this answer should be more upvoted than the accepted answer because it is applicable to multiple `\addplot` within the same `axis` environment and also allows scaling if you have additional features (e.g. error bars).

Comment: This is a great answer. Unfortulately, I could not find an answer on how to remove the scale from the finished plot (The *PI it shows in the bottom right in this example).